# How to load a 3d model from URL in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

What is the best way to load a 3d model from a URL inside of unity at runtime. I have tried this obj importer 
http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=ObjImporter

But the mesh in not imported properly. What other options exist? Assetbundle needs a pro version and even that won't solve as I need to load a 3d model from url. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use AssetBundles in the free version of Unity 5. Also, why can't you load a model from an AssetBundle? Just import into your project, make an asset bundle of it, download and instantiate it at run time.

Answer (score 2):

The way to go would be [asset bundles](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html). They are Unity's (proprietary) way to load prepackaged, compressed assets from a file or an URL. All asset bundles must be prepared and built in Unity Editor.

If you need a more general approach which loads a *raw* file format like fbx, obj, 3ds, collada, et cetera, you should use the [Assimp library](https://github.com/assimp). Assimp library is written in C++ but there is a wrapper for C#.NET [here](https://github.com/assimp/assimp-net).

There are also wrappers for Unity like [this Unity Assimp](https://github.com/akadjoker/UnityAssimp) being free but quite outdated. The Asset Store though is packed with [format specific importers](https://assetstore.unity.com/search?q=importer) including this free [OBJ importer](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/modeling/runtime-obj-importer-49547).

**2021 update**

Unity now also has [Addressables](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/com.unity.addressables.html) which are an evolution of the aforementioned Asset Bundles. In a sentence, Addressables are memory managed, asynchronously loadable resources that can be loaded from local or remote end points.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of libraries available to load 3d model from a URL in Unity.

These are the best two libraries to load the model from remote location at runtime.

- [Asynchronous Importer and run-time Loader for Unity](https://github.com/gpvigano/AsImpL)
- [Runtime OBJ Importer](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/modeling/runtime-obj-importer-49547#description)

Asynchronous Importer and run-time Loader for Unity is quite a useful tool to import obj files from a remote location with texture and materials. where the Runtime OBJ Importer might miss the texture/material of the model.

Demos:

https://github.com/codemaker2015/unity3d-runtime-model-importer
https://github.com/codemaker2015/Runtime-OBJ-Importer-Demo